# An NSMenuItem's view (instance of an NSView subclass) isn't highlighting on hover

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, highlight, nsview, nsmenuitem

I need to use a custom `NSView` subclass to draw some content, but it isn't drawing as highlighted when the user hovers and it doesn't dismiss the `NSMenu` when the user clicks on it. Any ideas?

#### Edit

So using `-drawRect:` and `[[self enclosingMenuItem] isHighlighted]` I'm able to tell whether or not I need to draw the view as highlighted and am given the chance to do so. All I have to figure out is how to do that.

Comment: By descendant, I think you mean subclass.

Comment: I don't want to change the title because links would break, but you're right.

Comment: Alexsander Akers: Links won't break, as the site actually doesn't pay attention to the title portion of the link. Only the question or answer number counts. To wit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917713/this-has-never-been-a-title-of-this-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should try it this way:

```
#define menuItem ([self enclosingMenuItem])

- (void) drawRect: (NSRect) rect {
    BOOL isHighlighted = [menuItem isHighlighted];
    if (isHighlighted) {
        [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] set];
        [NSBezierPath fillRect:rect];
    } else {
        [super drawRect: rect];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but [menuItem isHighlighted] returns NO all the time (even when the mouse is over the item). I assume the events are not propagated to the menuItem. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mark: Make sure your menu item is actually enabled. It needs an action set to a selector that exists. You can temporarily set your view to nil to make sure everything else is set up right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. I think you mean the following: The Menu opened and all your drawings stopped drawing. I think this is because the opened NSMenu stopps the UI' NSRunLoop its thread. One of both. You should try to do your drawing thread-safe in an other thread.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I use a Stackview. But this should work for views as well.

```
class MenuStackView: NSStackView {

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    let menuItem = self.enclosingMenuItem
    let isHighlighted = menuItem?.isHighlighted ?? false
    if isHighlighted {
        NSColor.selectedMenuItemColor.set()
        NSBezierPath.fill(dirtyRect)
    } 
}
}
```