# NSGradient into NSColor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nscolor, nsgradient

OK, long story short:

- I'm using (embedded into the bundle) FontAwesome
- I'm using it as the font in some custom `NSButton`s
- In the `NSButton` subclass I want to colour them, exactly the way the Xcode tab items are coloured

[image: Colour gradient Xcode]

This is how I'm setting the color (as a simple NSColor):

```
    NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.09 green:0.55 blue:0.90 alpha:1.0];
    NSMutableAttributedString *colorTitle =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[self attributedTitle]];

    NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, [colorTitle length]);

    [colorTitle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                       value:color
                       range:titleRange];

    [self setAttributedTitle:colorTitle];
```

How can I set it to an `NSGradient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's the solution, for anyone who may find useful...

**Step 1:**

Create a category on `NSColor`, based on the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643303/how-does-nscolor-selectedmenuitemcolor-magically-draw-a-gradient) by @Omz. In the code below, you'll see it renamed as `colorFromGradient:`, solely in order to mix well with the usual Cocoa naming conventions...

**Step 2:**

Redraw the title with the gradient color

```
    NSColor* gS = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.07 green:0.47 blue:0.87 alpha:1.0];
    NSColor* gE = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.12 green:0.64 blue:0.94 alpha:1.0];
    NSGradient* g = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:gE endingColor:gS];
    NSColor *color = [NSColor colorFromGradient:g];

    NSMutableAttributedString *colorTitle =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[self attributedTitle]];

    NSRange titleRange = NSMakeRange(0, [colorTitle length]);

    [colorTitle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                       value:color
                       range:titleRange];

    [self setAttributedTitle:colorTitle];
```

**Step 3:**

Enjoy the result. :-)

[image: NSGradient to NSColor applied to FontAwesome]

Comment: colorFromGradient: doesn't seem to be a valid API anymore.