# Exactly matching the background of a selected NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nscolor

I am creating a custom view for an `NSMenuItem`.  In order to draw the background when selected, I adapted a couple of lines from the [CustomMenus](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html) sample.  The CustomMenus sample has:

```
    [[NSColor alternateSelectedControlColor] set];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
```

.. and I am using the selectedMenuItemColor because the alternateSelectedControlColor was a solid color and it did not look very good:

```
    [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] set];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
```

Using selectedMenuItemColor is better, but it's still not exactly the same as a real selected `NSMenuItem`.

Here is a screenshot showing the real selected `NSMenuItem` background on the left and the selectedMenuItemColor on the right in the "Blue" appearance:

[image: Side-by-side comparison of the real selected menu item background and the selectedMenuItemColor in the "Blue" appearance]

You can see that there is an additional translucent white gradient overlay on the real selected `NSMenuItem` background.

How do I replicate the real selected `NSMenuItem` background?

**EDIT:** This is for Mac OS 10.9.5.

**EDIT2:** Here is a side-by-side comparison in the "Graphite" appearance:

[image: Side-by-side comparison of the real selected menu item background and the selectedMenuItemColor in the "Graphite" appearance]

Comment: You mean `pearlescent`. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through trial and error I came up with the following code that draws a background almost indistinguishable from the real selected `NSMenuItem` background in both "Blue" and "Graphite" appearances:

```
    [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] set];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);

    if (dirtyRect.size.height > 1) {
        const NSControlTint currentControlTint = [NSColor currentControlTint];

        const CGFloat startingOpacity = (NSBlueControlTint == currentControlTint ? (CGFloat)0.16 : (CGFloat)0.09);
        NSGradient *grad = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:startingOpacity] endingColor:[NSColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:(CGFloat)0.0]];

        const CGFloat heightMinus1 = (CGFloat)(dirtyRect.size.height - 1);
        [grad drawFromPoint:NSMakePoint(dirtyRect.origin.x, dirtyRect.origin.y + heightMinus1) toPoint:NSMakePoint(dirtyRect.origin.x, dirtyRect.origin.y + 1) options:0u];

        if (NSBlueControlTint == currentControlTint) {
            [[NSColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:(CGFloat)0.1] set];
            NSRectFillUsingOperation(NSMakeRect(dirtyRect.origin.x, dirtyRect.origin.y + heightMinus1, dirtyRect.size.width, (CGFloat)1.0), NSCompositeSourceOver);
        }
    }
```

Here are side-by-side comparisons:

[image: "Aqua" appearance comparison]

[image: "Graphite" appearance comparison]

The left halves (80px) of the two images show the real selected `NSMenuItem` background and the right halves of the two images are the result of the code.

Comment: Looks good. But keep in mind 10.10 is going to be a a lot more complex with dark mode, vibrancy and accessibility changes.

Comment: Just wanted to add a quick note that this appears to be a regression - OS X 10.6 draws the correct gradient for -[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor]. I'm not sure when it broke, but I get the same behavior as you on OS X 10.9.

Comment: I converted your code to Swift: https://gist.github.com/joelcox/28de2f0cb21ea47bd789

Answer (score 0):

It's not a translucent white gradient. It is drawing a gradient. 
To do that use NSGradient and NSBezierPath for drawing. 
Note, you also need to stay in line with what the user has preferred. Gray or Aqua style. This changes the menu highlight. 
Also, you are going to need to be prepared to do it differently on 10.10

Very differently. 
In 10.10 you will need to handle a combination of
vibrancy
Dark mode
Light mode
Accessibilty settings that further change the colors. 
Look at that now, and find all the notifications you should observe. but anticipate the colors are still moving targets.