# Custom NSMenuItem with right-aligned detail text label

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, nsmenu

**What I want to implement**

I am looking for a way to display a title label and a detail text label in a `NSMenuItem`.
Preferably it would look something like this: [image: NSMenuItem Example]

1. The Title Label is left aligned with all the other `NSMenuItem`'s
   titles
2. The Detail Text Label is right-aligned
3. The Detail Text Label has a different text color than the title
4. Selection/Submenus etc. work as expected

---

**What have I tried already**

By reading the documentation I found the following possible implementations:

1. Create a custom `NSView` and set `NSMenuItem.view`
2. Use a default `NSMenuItem` and use a `NSAttributedString`

First I tried to use a custom `NSView`. However I could not get the `NSMenuItem` to size correctly in order to display all the available text. I guess some autoresizing masks do not work correctly but I am not sure. Also this way I would need to re-implement selection/arrow for the submenu, ...

Then I started to experiment with `NSAttributedString`. I calculate the title with the most characters and then pad the string with `title += string.padding(toLength: maxTitleLength, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)`. The `NSAttributedString` colors the title and the detail label differently. However this does not seem to work since the detail labels are not correctly aligned although the title is padded to the same length. I guess this makes sense since characters have different widths?

---

**TL;DR - Question**

So is there any other way to implement the desired design which I did not find? Do you have any advice for me on how to implement this?

Comment: You might want to check NSMenuItemBadge introduced in macOS 14

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found the answer myself. Actually it works for me now by using the `view` property of the `NSMenuItem` to set a custom view. This answer lead me to the right direction: [Highlighting a NSMenuItem with a custom view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054331/highlighting-a-nsmenuitem-with-a-custom-view/8962256#8962256).